# codeigniter web servcies authenticate iphone's user

Tags: php, codeigniter

Are there any libraries for Codeigniter to authenticate an iPhone user via webservices?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you looking for when you say "iPhone user authentication via webservices" ? if they are accessing your site through safari browser, then you don't need any helpers or libraries, but simply authentication code that works properly in a browser.

If you're looking for helpers that convert your Codeigniter app and make it accessible via mobile browsers, then you're trying to find the wrong thing. Simply modify your CSS to support mobile browsers (screen size, font size etc) and you should be good. This should not impact your models or controllers in any way.